# How to use dispatch actions on android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-platform

I am working on a project hosted on AppEngine, and for the browser client I am using the GWTP platform which implies using GIN (on the client) and GUICE on the server. Also, it uses Models, presenters, actions and events.

I am thinking of also writing an android client for the service but I don't know how to start because I don't know how to connect and exchange data with the webservice. I would have to use Actions and Action Handlers ( http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStartedDispatch ) which I use for the browser client. From Android I only know how to do it with RPC, and I can't make the connection, I don't know how to map classes from the device to the server.

For example, by using GWTP, if on the browser client I want to do something on the server, I implement an Action class, an ActionResult class ( both on the client ) and an ActionHandler class (on the server). To dispatch an action, I use the DispatchAsync interface and to get the result I use AsyncCallback.

Action (on the client ) - SendRoadNotification.java :

```
public class SendRoadNotification extends
    ActionImpl<SendRoadNotificationResult> {

private RoadNotification roadNot;



@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private SendRoadNotification() {
    // For serialization only
    }

public SendRoadNotification(RoadNotification roadNot) {
    this.roadNot = roadNot;
    }

public RoadNotification getRoadNot() {
    return roadNot;
    }
}
```

ActionResult (on the client ) -- SendRoadNotfifcationResult.java :

```
public class SendRoadNotificationResult implements Result {

private RoadNotification roadNot;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private SendRoadNotificationResult() {
    // For serialization only
    }

public SendRoadNotificationResult(RoadNotification roadNot) {
    this.roadNot = roadNot;
    }

public RoadNotification getRoadNot() {
    return roadNot;
    }
}
```

ActionHandler ( on the server ) -- SendRoadNotificationActionHandler.java :

```
public class SendRoadNotificationActionHandler implements
    ActionHandler<SendRoadNotification, SendRoadNotificationResult> {

static DataStore ds = DataStore.getDatastoreService();

@Inject
public SendRoadNotificationActionHandler() {
    }

@Override
public SendRoadNotificationResult execute(SendRoadNotification action,
        ExecutionContext context) throws ActionException {

                        //Here I am doing something with that action
    }

@Override
public void undo(SendRoadNotification action,
        SendRoadNotificationResult result, ExecutionContext context)
        throws ActionException {
    }

@Override
public Class<SendRoadNotification> getActionType() {
    return SendRoadNotification.class;
        }
}
```

The way I use those, is:

```
    SendRoadNotification action = new SendRoadNotification(rn);
            dispatchAsync.execute(action, sendRoadNotifCallback);
```

And the callback:

```
AsyncCallback<SendRoadNotificationResult> sendRoadNotifCallback = new AsyncCallback<SendRoadNotificationResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(SendRoadNotificationResult result) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        Window.alert("Something went wrong");

    }

};
```

How can I implement this in android ? Can somebody give me an example or had this problem before ?

I am using AppEngine sdk 1.6.4, GWT sdk 2.4.0, GWTP plugin for Eclipse and GPE plugin for Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the source the GAE plugin for ADT generates for 'App Engine Connected Android apps' for inspiration. They are doing something similar by calling GWT endpoints using Android's HttpClient.

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_connected_android

Comment: Hi. Thanks, I have seen that project, but It doesn't work well when integrated with GWTP plugin for eclipse. I would just need a short sample on how to merge gwt-platform plugin with appengine and an Android client. Can you help me with that, or at least give me a hint on the flow of everything ?

Comment: Create a small test project using the wizard and check out the source code. It might not work as is for your project, but you will get an idea about how to implement the Android side of things.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov are you want to create android app for client? or use same app but mobile compatible using android webview feature?